# How to sort datetime index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a datetime index dataframe which contains data for every hour between 2019 and 2020 and which I import from a CSV file as follow in order to keep only the columns I want, with easier names (names are changed for work reasons):

```
file = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=";", header=0, na_values=['NA', ' ' , '.'])
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['week'] = df['datetime'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['month'] = df['datetime'].dt.month
df['hour']=df['datetime'].dt.hour
df['day']=df['datetime'].dt.day

df=df.set_index(['datetime'])
   

df=df.rename(columns={'data1':'d1','data2':'d2','data3':'d3','data4':'d4','data5':'d5','data6':'d6','data7':'d7','data8':'d8','data9':'d9','data10':'d10','data11':'d11','data12':'d12','data13':'d13','data14':'d14','data15':'d15','data16':'d16'})

df=df[['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','d10','d11','d12','d13','d14','d15','d16','week','month','hour','day']]
```

When I'm typing :

```
df['d4'][0:2800].min()
```

The answer is 995 which I know is the good answer cause I checked on the CSV file.

Now my problem is that during importation, some dates are put in the dataframe in wrong orders. I don't know why but for example 2019-09-09 will be followed by 2019-09-13 instead of 2019-09-10 .

I tried to fix it by using

```
df=df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

or

```
df=df.sort_index()
```

and it seems to work as now all the dates are in the good order, but now that I type

```
df['d4'][0:2800].min()
```

the answer is now 870 which is a wrong value.

It seems like df.sort_index() is mixing my data, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: what is the input format of `df['datetime']`, before you call `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`?

Comment: Hello, it's a string
The form is '01/01/2019 00:00'

Comment: so, what comes first, day or month?

Comment: Day in the CSV files in str type, month in the dataframe datetime indexed.
For exemple christmas is 25/12/2019 in the CSV file but 2019-12-25 in the datetime indexed dataframe

Comment: Ok that's important; can you change your code to `df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=True)` and see if that helps?

Comment: It works thanks a lot! Can't believe I did'nt think about that... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The point here is to make sure date/time is imported correctly to datetime datatype. A string like `'01/01/2019 00:00'` will be parsed by default as `mm/dd/YYYY HH:MM`, see [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime):

> dayfirst bool, default False

Depending on where you live, you might expect that the day comes first.

Also note that this is evaluated for each element; e.g. `'25-12-2019'` is parsed to Dec 25th since there is no month 25. But `'03-12-2019'` from the same column becomes March 12th although Dec 3rd might be expected. That can create quite a mess. So if...

***day comes first in your date string:***

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=True)
```

You could also

- provide the [parsing directive](https://strftime.org/) explicitly via the `format` kwarg of `to_datetime`
- specify a column to be parsed to datetime via the `parse_dates` kwarg of [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). There, you can also specify `dayfirst=True`